# installation of Turn server using cygwin on windows 7

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc, turn

I have followed the steps as provided in the below link
https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/TURN-server-installation-guide.html#windows

The issue is i am unable to run the turn server on my public ip, the log file shows error
Wrong user account,
Trying to bind DTLS/UDP listener socket to addr 192.168.8.100:3478
although the user credential are same as set in turnserver.conf file further i have not provided the '192.168.8.100' as this is not my public ip

Please help i need to configure turn server on my machine so that i can make video call app to communicate cross network

Comment: I think 192.168.8.100 is your LAN ip.
Do you have public IP directly assigned to your machine? (check ipconfig)
What is your turnserver config?

Comment: I have changed the configuration to 127.0.0.1:4378 and have tested the server using the below link : https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/ the candidates are gathering when i hit the app login but in case of cross network video is not streamed of the remote peer, i am using signalr as the signalling server

Comment: You must have a public IP for turn server. Read the basics @ https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/